# Converting Long 64-bit Decimal to Binary

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, cocoa, binary

OK, what I'm trying to accomplish is fairly straightforward although I'm still having issues.

**This is my code :**

```
- (NSString*)toBin:(long)dec
{
    long num = dec;
    NSString *res = [NSString string];

    for (long i=63; i>=0; i--)
    {
        long div = 1<<i;
        if ((num&div)==div) res = [res stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
        else res = [res stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
    }

    return res;
}
```

**And this is how I'm testing it :**

```
    for (long i=1; i<10; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%u = %@",i,[self toBin:(long)i]);
    }
```

However, the output of the above is :

```
1 = 0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001
2 = 0000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000010
3 = 0000000000000000000000000000001100000000000000000000000000000011
4 = 0000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000100
5 = 0000000000000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000000000101
6 = 0000000000000000000000000000011000000000000000000000000000000110
7 = 0000000000000000000000000000011100000000000000000000000000000111
8 = 0000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001000
9 = 0000000000000000000000000000100100000000000000000000000000001001
```

So, it's *almost* correct (as for the last 32 bits), though it seems to be duplicating itself for the top 32 bits. I guessed it had something to do with my `long` size, but `sizeof(long)` returns `8`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression:

```
long div= 1<<i;
```

Is an int, not a long.So you get an integer of just 32 bits (pardon if I speak only for my machine).So just produce a 64 bit expression:

```
long div = 1l<<i;
```